# What does an apostrophe on top of a note mean?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, articulation, ornaments

In my music (Trombone/Baritone), I see an apostrophe on top of a few notes. What does this mean?

[image: picture of notes with mark]

Comment: My bet right now is that it's an alternate or poorly-typeset *[staccatissimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staccato#Staccatissimo)*, but without finding another example with explanation it's just a guess.

Comment: I've found a few other examples that look like that in a google image search but without the ability to zoom in so close and be sure in any of them (low res images).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [staccatissimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staccato#Staccatissimo)  or wedge. The note is sustained for one quarter the written length, the remaining three quarters being silent. As commented by Matt these durations are open to interpretation by the performer.

Comment: Yes, it's a staccatissimo, but it's not correct to say rigidly that it's 1/4 length.  The exact length is always a matter of style.